# Is there a remedy for the choppiness of Bootstrap's accordion JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap framework and I thought I'd make use of their [accordion layout](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-examples). However, on their example page, it seems a bit choppy<sup>1</sup> when testing on Chrome and Safari desktop browsers. Though some of the results vary in the desktop browsers, it seems to always have a choppy motion on the iPhone and iPad.

Question: Is this just the way it is? Is there anyway to improve the speed and fluid motion of the accordion layout, or perhaps there's a better known accordion layout?

<sup>1</sup> By choppy, I mean that it doesn't open and close in a fluid motion **consistently**.

Comment: worse comes to worse, you could fork a copy from github, and try to improve it. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

Comment: It's choppy because it uses javascript rather than css to animate the accordion.

Answer (score 1):

Here, test this out.

http://jsfiddle.net/JA7qY/

Just a little snippet of what I did (view the rest in the fiddle):

```
$("[data-toggle='slider']").click( function(e) {
    var next_of_kin = "[data-parent='" + e.target.id + "']";
    $(next_of_kin).toggleClass('close');
});
```

All I did was expand upon jQuery's data-toggles and rather than just changing height values via javascript, I changed them by adding and removing classes which allows for css transitions (smooth animations) to be used.